# Generalized Gaussian integral with imaginary coefficient

Tags: integration, calculus, complex-numbers

From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368186/gaussian-integral-with-imaginary-coefficients-and-wick-rotation) question and answers, one can prove the following identity (the Gaussian integral for the case of purely imaginary coefficients) holds:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ \exp\left(iax^2+iJx\right)=\left(\frac{\pi i}{a}\right)^{1/2}\exp\left(\frac{-iJ^2}{4a}\right), \qquad a,J\in\mathbb{R}. $$

I'm looking a slight generalization, where the integrand is the same except for multiplication by a power of $x$:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ x^n\exp\left(i\frac{a}{2}x^2+iJx\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi i}{a}\right)^{1/2}\exp\left(\frac{-iJ^2}{2a}\right), \qquad a,J\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Particularly, I am interested in the cases where $n$ equals $1$ or $2$. We know that for $a>0$ the standard integrals are
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ xe^{-ax^2+bx} = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{4a^3}be^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}, \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ x^2e^{-ax^2+bx} = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{16a^5}(2a+b^2)e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}. $$

Am I correct in assuming that, for example, the first integral generalises as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ xe^{iax^2+iJx} = \sqrt\frac{i\pi}{4a^3}Je^{-\frac{iJ^2}{4a}} $$

and similarly for the second?

Comment: The standard method is to take the derivatives with $J$ (moment generating function)

Comment: @LPZ Don't know why I didn't think of that, thank you. So it turns out that my assumption was off by a minus sign.